# C# - convert lat long coordinates to WKT format

Tags: coordinate-system, c#, coordinates, mercator

How can I convert coordinates to WKT format like `39.8251136,-8.3824103` with 900913 system (spherical Mercator)?

My client is askying me something like this: `SRID=900913;POINT(-939520.0088637
4744291.7338414)` but I already search about this and I don't find anything.

I found this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561186/converting-lat-long-to-pointclass but I don't know where I can find the DLL with the `SpatialReferenceEnvironmentClass` class for I can test that code...

Comment: That's not WKT, but **EWKT**, which is PostGIS-specific.

Comment: It looks like you want to project *then* serialize the coordinate. I'm not a C# programmer, but it looks like there are several libraries available to do the job that don't require ESRI libraries. For example, [DotSpatial](https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial). Tutorials [here](https://dotspatial.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DotSpatial%20Tutorials&referringTitle=Documentation).